# Xcode 8 : Enable wireless capability for Wildcard App ID

Tags: ios, xcode8

I'm using **Wildcard App Id** for development profile.

Now in Xcode 8 it's required **Wireless Accessory Configuration capability** must be enable in project setting as well as in app id. I have enable this capability in project setting under capability section but I'm not able to enable this capability for wildcard app id.

Is there any way to enable this capability in wildcard app id or we can bypass this requirement?

Answer (score 4):

**You should use a Wildcard App ID for all apps and app targets that do not enable app-specific capabilities.**

So I am afraid you can not use this capability with Wildcard App Id.

> **Using a Wildcard App ID is convenient for all apps that do not use
>   capabilities, as they can reuse the same provisioning profile for code
>   signing**.

Here is complete Q/A discussion about [When should I use a wildcard App ID](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1713/_index.html)?

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

You can only enable a limited number of capabilities in your WildCard AppId. The reason being most other capabilities rely on the bundle identifier like **Push notifications**, **App groups** etc.

You will have to create a new App Id with desired bundle identifier & enable the required capabilities there.

Comment: It's not allowing even if I create a new wildcard app id. so this issue is not related to capabilities limitation.

Comment: @KiritVaghela by creating "new App id" means not a wildcard app id.

Comment: @Muhammad Adnan Yes but I can select which type of app id I want to create Wildcard or Explicit . When I select wildcard app id than Wireless Accessory Configuration capability become disable.

Comment: you have to create explicit app id. Check the options then

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan for explicit app id it's allows but I don't want to create a explicit app id.

Comment: @KiritVaghela I'm afraid but that's how it works. You have to create an explicit app id, there is no other way.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no way of using the Wireless Accessory Configuration Capability with a Wildcard App ID**

If you want to use this capability, create an *Explicit App ID*. Xcode is able to do this for you automatically, but if you'd like to read more on the topic please check out [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html) guide.

Answer (score 0):

No chance in **Wildcard App ID** but i find some thing through **[apple](https://developer.apple.com)**
not sure about it:

> Xcode 8 reports an error because of the missing In-app purchase that
>   never included in a wildcard profile,
>
> removing the problematic capabilities  stops the application from
>   being linked, and adding those frameworks again enables the
>   capabilities again! So  remove the capabilities, and then link the
>   framework by adding them to the 'Other linker flags' in the build
>   settings. (-framework StoreKIt)